# How to use schema.core/enum in clojure?

Tags: clojure, enums

Given an enum made from prismatic `schema.core/enum`, let's say:

```
(def myenumtype (schema.core/enum "a" "b" "c"))
```

How can I set another def to a specific enum item?   Here I would like to set `e` to the "a" enum item.

```
(def e (???  myenumtype))
```

And how can I compare this to a specific enum?  Here I would like to check to see if `e` is equal to the `"a"` enum type.

```
(= e ((??? "a") myenumtype))
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're misunderstanding how Schema works. You're not creating an enum type, you're creating a validator that checks if a particular value equals one of the enumerated values.

In your case, all you need to do is:

```
(def e "a")
```

Here's an example REPL session:

```
user=> (schema.core/validate (schema.core/enum "a" "b" "c") "a")
"a"
=> (schema.core/validate (schema.core/enum "a" "b" "c") "z")
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Value does not match schema: (not (#{"a" "b" "c"} "z"))
```